# error: implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed (vector of structs)

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting my C++ program to compile. Would really appreciate some help with this error. In the header file, I have this:

```
struct workerT{
 workerT() : status(true), threadSem(0){}
 bool status;
 std::function<void(void)> func;
 semaphore threadSem;
};

std::vector<workerT> workers;
```

In my .cc file, I am trying to initialize that vector like this:

```
fill(workers.begin(), workers.end(), workerT());
```

This fails with the error:
error: ‘TP::workerT& TP::workerT::operator=(const TP::workerT&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
It points to the semaphore.h file. Semaphore.h is defined like this:

```
 public:
  semaphore(int value = 0);
  ....

private:
  int value;
  ....
  semaphore(const semaphore& orig) = delete;
  const semaphore& operator=(const semaphore& rhs) const = delete;
```

The program compiles if I remove the "fill" line, but I really need that because I want to initialize the vector. I get the same error message when I make a dummy struct and try to push_back into the vector.

Update: thanks @DyP! I still need help compiling. Replaced the "fill" line with this:

```
std::generate(workers.begin(), workers.end(), free_func);
```

Added exactly this to my header:

```
workerT free_func(){
 return {};
}
```

Getting these errors:

thread-pool.cc: In constructor ‘ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t)’:
thread-pool.cc:33:58: error: argument of type ‘ThreadPool::workerT (ThreadPool::)()’ does not match ‘ThreadPool::workerT (ThreadPool::*)()’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
                 from thread-pool.cc:15:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::generate(_FIter, _FIter, _Generator) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, _Generator = ThreadPool::workerT (ThreadPool::*)()]’:
thread-pool.cc:33:58:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5013:2: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘__gen (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* __gen) (...)’
make: *** [thread-pool.o] Error 1

Update-- In my .cc file:

```
 using namespace std;

 static workerT free_func(){
   return {};
 }

 ThreadPool(...args...){
   std::generate(workers.begin(), workers.end(), free_func);
 }
```

Errors:

```
thread-pool.cc:19:10: error: ‘workerT’ does not name a type
thread-pool.cc: In constructor ‘ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t)’:
thread-pool.cc:39:49: error: ‘free_func’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [thread-pool.o] Error 1
```

Update again:

```
 static ThreadPool::workerT free_func(){
    return {};
 }

 ThreadPool(...args...){
   std::generate(workers.begin(), workers.end(), free_func);
 }
```

In thread-pool.h:

```
 struct workerT{
 workerT() : status(true), threadSem(0){}
 bool status;
 std::function<void(void)> func;
 semaphore threadSem;
};
```

Comment: `semaphore(const semaphore& orig) = delete;` That means your semaphore type is not copyable. Is it movable?

Comment: how can I find out? The other line in the header file is

Comment: The implementation of `std::fill` attempts to copy-assign each `workerT` element. It can't do so if the copy-assignment operator of their data members are deleted.

Comment: const semaphore& operator=(const semaphore& rhs) const = delete;

Comment: @0x499602D2, so std::fill won't work? Does push_back on a vector do the same thing? How else can I fill my vector?

Comment: `push_back` will copy-construct (or move) each element into the vector. If your `semaphore` object is copy-constructible, it will work.

Comment: I can not reproduce your error, it works in gcc. [Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eba6744615af6d0)

Comment: @MM. copy-assignment is probably deleted, too.

Comment: @user2057841 A comment is not enough, please edit your question and add that line (`const semaphore& operator=(const semaphore& rhs) const = delete;`) to the last code snippet (after `semaphore(const semaphore& orig) = delete;`) as you should have done to begin with...

Comment: The new error message seems to be another, rather unrelated problem. What is <strike>`TP`</strike>`ThreadPool`? (I suppose it's a type, so how does it look like?)

Comment: @DyP just edited again. TP is ThreadPool, the class name. The struct and vector are defined in thread-pool.h, and I'm trying to fill the vector in thread-pool.cc. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: It almost looks like you have put `free_func` as a member function in the `ThreadPool` class? Either make it `static` or a true *free* (= non-member) function (can also put it into the .cc only, make it static for internal linkage).

Comment: @DyP I don't quite understand. I added static and moved the function into the .cc file, but now I get other errors:    thread-pool.cc:19:10: error: ‘workerT’ does not name a type
thread-pool.cc: In constructor ‘ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t)’:
thread-pool.cc:39:49: error: ‘free_func’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [thread-pool.o] Error 1

Comment: Well this now looks like an issue with the order of declarations and possibly scope (e.g. `free_func` needs to be declared after including the header, and it must be visible at the point where you call `generate`). Please compose an example so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DyP thanks, I just updated my post. The code I added comes after I included the header, but outside of where I call generate.

Comment: Isn't `workerT` a type defined inside `ThreadPool`? Shouldn't the `free_func` therefore be declared as `static ThreadPool::workerT free_func()` (with a more appropriate name ;) or not at all -- see the middle section of my answer)

Comment: @DyP thanks but I'm still having trouble. Now I'm getting the same implicitly declared error again :(

Comment: As gx_ has pointed out, there need to be an explicit move constructor and move assignment operator in `semaphore` in order for `semaphore` to be movable. Look for a signature like `semaphore(semaphore&&)` and `semaphore& operator=(semaphore&&)`. If `semaphore` is *not* movable, you're pretty much out of luck and have to store it as a pointer (e.g. `unique_ptr`) in `workerT`.

Comment: Oh there is no constructor like that.. The only constructors here are the 2 I included in my description. Could you give an example of how I can add the pointer to my struct and initialize this vector? Thanks so much for all your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [0x499602d2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2) correctly pointed out, `fill` needs to copy-assign from the third argument. As your type implicitly is noncopyable, you cannot use `fill`.

You could, however, use `generate` to fill your vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct noncopyable
{
    noncopyable() = default;

    // make it noncopyable
    noncopyable(noncopyable const&) = delete;
    noncopyable& operator=(noncopyable const&) = delete;

    // make it movable (thanks, gx_)
    noncopyable(noncopyable&&) = default;
    noncopyable& operator=(noncopyable&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<noncopyable> vec(10);
    std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), []()->noncopyable{return {};});
}
```

Note: this only works if `noncopyable` has a non-deleted, accessible move constructor. However, if it *does not* have such a ctor, you won't be able to use much of the vector (`resize` requires `MoveInsertable`, which requires either a copy- or move-ctor).

---

For g++4.8, to use `generate`, you'll need a free function. I think that's a bug.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct noncopyable
{
    noncopyable() = default;
    noncopyable(noncopyable const&) = delete;
};

noncopyable free_func()
{  return {};  }

int main()
{
    std::vector<noncopyable> vec;
    std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), free_func);
}
```

---

Yet another question is if you can *initialize* your vector like that. I'd say NO. `fill` and `generate` do not *construct* elements, but overwrite (assign). That is, you'll already need to have a vector with multiple elements before you can use them.

The easiest version to *initialize* a vector with N default-constructed elements is to use the constructor:

```
std::vector<noncopyable> vec(10);
```

Creates a `vector` with 10 default-constructed elements. The only requirement is that `noncopyable` is DefaultConstructible (essentially, it must have a default constructor).

---

If your type is noncopyable AND nonmovable, you cannot use it directly (or as a data member) to store it inside a `vector`(*). To make a class `C` movable, which contains a noncopyable, nonmovable type `X`, you need to store `X` as a pointer:

<sub>(*) Well, you can, but you cannot resize the vector, you cannot insert etc.</sub>

```
struct nocopies_nomoves
{
    nocopies_nomoves() = default;

    nocopies_nomoves(nocopies_nomoves const&) = delete;
    nocopies_nomoves& operator=(nocopies_nomoves const&) = delete;

    // not required to be explicitly deleted:
    nocopies_nomoves(nocopies_nomoves&&) = delete;
    nocopies_nomoves& operator=(nocopies_nomoves&&) = delete;
};

#include <utility>
#include <memory>
class C
{
public:
    C() : ptr( new nocopies_nomoves() ) {} // make_unique in C++1y

    // I don't think you need to explicitly define those as defaulted;
    // at least not if you don't declare ANY of the copy/move ctors, assignment ops
    // and dtor
    C(C&& rhs) = default;
    C& operator=(C&& rhs) = default;
    ~C() = default;

    // not required to be explicitly deleted:
    C(C const&) = delete;
    C& operator=(C const&) = delete;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<nocopies_nomoves> ptr;
};
```

Now you can create a `vector<C>` and use it (e.g. `resize`, `insert`, ...)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static C generate_C()
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<C> vec(10);
    // note: futile statement below; overwrites the 10 default-constructed
    //       elements
    std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), generate_C);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Huh? I just tested it with clang++3.4. The type has an implicit move ctor and move-assignment operator.

Comment: GCC 4.8 doesn't compile it.

Comment: yeah it doesn't compile for me too

Comment: @0x499602D2 Btw this isn't copy/move elision. The type is directly constructed into the return value.

Comment: I replaced my original "fill" line with this:    generate(begin(workers), end(workers), []()->workerT{return {};});

Comment: Thanks so much for ur help! But I'm still getting this error     implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

Comment: @user2057841 I think I'd need a [complete example](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem at this point

Comment: @user2057841 Is your semaphore allowed to be move-assignable?

Comment: @DyP thanks I have fewer errors now! But still not compiling. Now I get "/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5013:2: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘__gen (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* __gen) (...)’
make: *** [thread-pool.o] Error 1

Comment: @DyP Since the copy constructor is deleted, the compiler won't auto-generate a move constructor. Moreover a "noncopyable" type usually has a deleted copy constructor _and_ a deleted copy assignment operator, which will also prevent the generation of the move assignment operator (and thus `std::generate` can't be used either).

Comment: @gx_ The circumstances under which a move ctor and move-assignment operator are deleted are quite complex. Looking into 12.8, I don't see why the move ctor should be deleted just because the copy ctor is deleted (similarly for the assignment operator).

Comment: @DyP The move-ctor is not "deleted", it is just not implicitly generated by the compiler. 12.8/9 "If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
as defaulted if and only if
— `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
(...)", and `noncopyable(noncopyable const&) = delete;` is a user-declared copy constructor

Comment: @gx_ You're right; for some reason I thought I had tested it and the results were different.